# If a search yields no results is it possible to show an alternative set of results?

Tags: theming, search

I'm using Views to override a search administered through Search API. If a search yields no results is it possible to show an alternative set of results? For example, if I searched for "grettrr" and no results were found I'd get the usual "No results found" message, but underneath this message another message that says "Take a look at these instead" would display along with a set of alternative results. These alternative results could be shown based on specified taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible: Under the "Advanced" panel of your view (collapsed to the right of the screen), add a new behaviour to the "No results behaviour", then add a "Global: view area" reaction. You can add any view there.